# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. If for all $a, b \in G$, there exists a $k \in G$ such that $(aH)(bH)=kH$, then show that $k=ab$.

Tags: group-theory

This is the question I'm stuck on.

> Let $H$ be a sugroup of $G$. If for all $a, b \in G$, there exists a $k \in G$ such that $(aH)(bH)=kH$, then show that $k=ab$.

That means that if $(aH)(bH)$ is still somehow a left coset of $H$ for all $a,b \in H$, then this left coset must be $abH$. $(aH)(bH)$ is defined as $\{ah_1 bh_2 \mid h_1, h_2 \in H\}$. I understand that such an operation is $\textbf{well defined}$ only if $H$ is a normal subgroup, but the question doesn't impose any constraints on $H$. It only asks that $k$ must be equal to $ab$. I'm not sure how to proceed.

So far I've tried using the fact that different cosets are disjoint, and writing out an element of $(aH)(bH)$ as some $ah_1 bh_2 = kh_3$, but it doesn't seem to lead anywhere. Even if I let $a$ be identity and vary $b$, it doesn't show that $k=b$ because I get $b= kh_3 h_2^{-1}$, which isn't strong enough to imply that $b= k$.

EDIT: Saying that $k=ab$ is wrong, I think the original intent was to show that the coset of $(aH)(bH)$ is the same as the coset $abH$ without any presumption of $H$ being normal.

Comment: $\exists k, \forall a,b$ or $\forall a,b, \exists k$ ?

Comment: Note that $kH=abH$ does not in any way imply $k=ab$.

Comment: The latter, for all $a, b$, there exists $k$. Sorry about that, I'll edit the question soon

Comment: Right, have edited the question

Comment: As it is, the statement is still false. Because you can choose $k=abh$ for any $h\in H$. Did you meant to say "if $(aH)(bH)=kH$ for some $k$ then $kH=abH$"?

Comment: @freakish I see, that makes a lot of sense actually, it's because I can "tweak" my $k$ with a member of $h$ to force it not be be $ab$ anymore. I believe I have to ask the original setter of the question for that, but I think the intent is to show that $(aH)(bH)$ is the coset 'represented' by $ab$.

Comment: @YipJungHon yes, that's what I wrote in my previous comment. And that makes sense now.

Comment: However, if the question was: "show that $(aH)(bH)$ is the coset $(ab)(H)$, without any condition about $H$ being normal, just having the condition that for all $a,b \in G$, it is equal to some $kH$", would it still be a true statement?

Comment: What is $(aH)(bH)$? Is it $\{ah_1bh_2:h_1,h_2\in H\}$?

Comment: Yes, it's defined as such, see the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup. Suppose $a,b\in G$ are such that $(aH)(bH)$ is a left coset of $H$. Then we claim $(aH)(bH)=abH$. Indeed, since $H$ contains the identity, we have
$$
ab\in (aH)(bH) \cap abH
$$
So $(aH)(bH)$ and $abH$ are two left cosets of $H$ that intersect nontrivially. So they must be equal since the left cosets of $H$ form a partition.

*Remark:* This proof works for just one pair $(a,b)$ satisfying the assumptions. In other words, you don't need to make the assumption *for all* $a,b\in G$.